# When I try to declare a function inside of a function it doesn't work? Any suggestions? *source code below*

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a virtual bank(not a real one of course, just for fun) I'm trying to venture off on my own, and I've run into some problems I can't find a way around. The source code below doesn't work because I'm declaring a function inside of another function(I think) It is throwing back 2 errors: 'Login': identifier not found and 'SignUp': identifier not found. Any insight or help fixing this problem for any other problems in my code are appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
string username;
string password;
string EntryChoice;


void Bank()
{
 //cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
 system("cls");
 cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ";
 cout << "WELCOME TO THE BANK OF UNITED ARABS";
 cout << " <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\n";
 cout << "TO LOGIN TYPE (LOGIN) THEN PRESS ENTER:\n";
 cout << "TO SIGN UP TYPE (SIGN UP) THEN PRESS ENTER:\n";
 cin >> EntryChoice;
}
void BankCheck()
{
 while (EntryChoice != "LOGIN" || EntryChoice != "login" || EntryChoice != "Login" || EntryChoice != "SIGN UP" || EntryChoice != "Sign up" || EntryChoice != "Sign Up" || EntryChoice != "sign up")
 {
     Bank();
 }
 if (EntryChoice != "LOGIN" || EntryChoice != "login" || EntryChoice != "Login")
 {
     Login();
 }
 else if (EntryChoice != "SIGN UP" || EntryChoice != "Sign up" || EntryChoice != "Sign Up" || EntryChoice != "sign up")
 {
     SignUp();
 }
}
void Login()
{
 system("cls");
 cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ";
 cout << "BANK OF UNITED ARABS LOGIN PAGE";
 cout << " <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<";

}
void SignUp()
{

}
int main()
{
 Bank();


 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error arises because both Login() and Signup() are defined after BankCheck(), hence they are not visible to it yet. You need to either forward declare your Login() and Signup() functions before the Bankcheck() function definition, or move both their definitions before the BankCheck() function.

Answer (score 0):

You must have function identifier for `Login()` and `SignUp()` or put those function above `Bank()` function:

[function identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7h0c.png)